# Math.random() return wrong values and can't figure out why

Tags: java, random

I've got an assignment in Java that is a card game like War. I have to set values for 1-13 to signify cards and pick them at random. I've declared my variables and set them to have a max value, but I still get values that are well over 13. I've used `Math.random()` many times before with no problems whatsoever. I haven't condensed the code and probably some bloated lines and other lines just need not be there but it shouldn't affect my `Math.random()` numbers. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
class Card {

   public int cardNum;
   public int cardSuit1;
   public int cardSuit2;
   public final int CARDS_IN_SUIT;

     public Card() 
    {
        this.CARDS_IN_SUIT = 13;
        this.cardSuit1 = 4;
        this.cardSuit2 =4;
    }
     public void setCardNum1(int card)
   {
      cardNum = card;
   }
     public int getCardNum1()
   {
       if ((cardNum > 13) || (cardNum < 1))
       {
         cardNum = (((int) (Math.random() * 100 % CARDS_IN_SUIT + 1)));
       }
      return cardNum;
   }

     public void setCardNum2(int card)
   {
      cardNum = card;
   }
     public int getCardNum2()
   {
      cardNum = (((int) (Math.random() * 100 % CARDS_IN_SUIT + 1)));
      return cardNum;
   }
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
class DisplayCard      
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       final int CARDS_IN_SUIT = 13;
       final int cardNum = (((int) (Math.random() * 100 % CARDS_IN_SUIT + 1))); 
       Card firstCard = new Card();
       Card secondCard = new Card();
       firstCard.setCardNum1(cardNum);

       secondCard.setCardNum2(cardNum);
```

Comment: "I haven't condensed the code and probably some bloated lines and other lines just need not be there but it shouldn't affect my Math.random() numbers." So please *do* condense the code into a [mcve]. Hint: you probably only need about 10 lines of code to demonstrate the problem...

Comment: alright, I just didn't know how much was needed to be seen by more trained eyes that could be causing my problem.

Comment: Diagnosing the problem as far as you can is an important skill for an engineer. I strongly advise you to get practice at it while you have relatively trivial tasks like this one, so that you have a much better chance when coming up against something really hard. Then, either you won't need to ask a question at all (having solved it yourself) or your question will be a much better one, with a [mcve]. Research and trying to fix the problem yourself should always come *before* asking a question on SO.

Comment: You'd be better served to instantiate a `Random` object and use [nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-).  That will avoid the casting and modulo bias in your current implementation.

Comment: In addition to what was said, learn how to use a debugger. Helps you see where things go wrong. Other than that, you could also use some print commands in between to see where it goes wrong.